# vagrant up hanging on “Sending SSH keep-alive…”

Tags: virtualbox, centos

This issue happened when there are 2 NIC on centos7, 1st is default NAT enp0s3, 2nd is hostonly private network interface enp0s8.

vagrant did "service network restart" via ssh before enable enp0s8, but hanging there so from debug we only see "ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive".

vagrant up --debug

```
# Restart network
service network restart
(sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: 41e57d38-b4f7-4e46-9c38-13873d338b86-vagrant-ssh
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
```

only remedy works for me:

- ctrl-c to stop "vagrant up" when it is hanging
- power off vm from virtualbox GUI or CLI since "vagrant halt" also will take long time
- run "vagrant up" again it will start 2nd interface easily

Found lots of similar post from Internet but cannot find what is cause.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Vagrant issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/6207) for a potential solution.